# aws-sdk CodeCommit large batch getFile operations returning non-retryable 400 errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am calling the AWS CodeCommit getFolder API with the javascript sdk, and using the file listing, am then retrieving each file from the repository folder to inspect the content.

However, in larger folders (60+ files) this results in many AWS CodeCommit getFile calls.

If a handful of these run at the same time, I start to see retryable ThrottlingExceptions. I have a customBackoff callback for the CodeCommit client like so which handles these retryable errors just fine:

```
retryDelayOptions: {
        customBackoff: (retryCount, err) => {
            console.warn(`Retry ${retryCount}. We hit a retryable error`, err);
            return 1000 + (1000 * Math.pow(3, retryCount));
        }
    }
```

However, after some time (and pretty consistently) AWS CodeCommit returns a 400 BadRequest error that is non-retryable, and the whole procedure fails as the customBackoff / retry callback doesn't work in these cases.

Some of the error detail:

```
code: 'UnknownError',
statusCode: 400,
time: 2022-10-13T10:16:56.723Z,
requestId: 'xyz',
retryable: false
```

There is no other useful information from the API response - I've even dug into the installed aws-sdk node_module package and added additional logging there.

Is this an AWS back end service error that is unavoidable? Is there any pattern to use to avoid this?

One option I can think of is to instead see if I can use the sdk to clone the entire repo, which would hopefully just be one API call, then work on the files locally.

The Common Errors page does not list this error at all, which is frustrating. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html

Answer (score 0):

After thinking it through I came up with two potential solutions to my problem.

To clarify, I needed to iterate over many files in the repository and inspect their contents to do lookups of a provided 'name' to an 'id'. The file contents contained the name, and the file itself was named with the id. So iteration over all files was needed to locate the one with the searched 'name'.

Refactor solutions

- Clone the entire CodeCommit repository and do all the operations I needed on the 'local' file system. This would only require one or two AWS CodeCommit API calls (instead of potentially hundreds the original solution required at scale)
- Create a collection of symbolic links in the repository in the upstream system, with each being named with the `name`. (Names were guaranteed unique). Each symbolic link is created pointing to the relevant id file in the same repo. Now it is no longer required to iterate every file - I just simply do one getFile API call to see if the symbolic link with provided `name` exists, and if it does, the pointer can be used to identify the id and get the actual content of the file too.

I went with the second option above.